# CUDA: Unified Memory and change of pointer address?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, unified-memory

I'm using cuBlas to create a library for some matrix operations. I first implemented a matrix mult

Snippet of library header class (.h file)

```cpp
#include "cusolverDn.h"  // NOLINT
#include "cuda_runtime.h"  // NOLINT
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"  // NOLINT

namespace perception_core {
namespace matrix_transform {

class CudaMatrixTransformations {
 public:
  CudaMatrixTransformations();

  ~CudaMatrixTransformations();

  void MatrixMultiplicationDouble(double *A, double *B, double *C, const int m, const int k, const int n);

 private:
  // Cublas stuff
  cudaError_t cudaStat1;
  cudaError_t cudaStat2;
  cublasHandle_t cublasH;
  cublasStatus_t cublas_status;


};

}  // namespace matrix_transform
}  // namespace perception_core

#endif  // LIB_CUDA_ROUTINES_INCLUDE_MATRIX_TRANSFORMS_H_
```

Snippet of library class implementation for multiplication (.cu file)

```cpp
// This calculates the matrix mult C(m,n) = A(m,k) * B(k,n)
void CudaMatrixTransformations::MatrixMultiplicationDouble(
    double *A, double *B, double *C, int m, int k, const int n) {

      // Calculate size of each array
      size_t s_A = m * k;
      size_t s_B = k * n;
      size_t s_C = m * n;

      // Create the arrays to use in the GPU
      double *d_A = NULL;
      double *d_B = NULL;
      double *d_C = NULL;


      // Allocate memory
      cudaStat1 = cudaMallocManaged(&d_A, s_A * sizeof(double));
      cudaStat2 = cudaMallocManaged(&d_B, s_B * sizeof(double));
      assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
      assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
      cudaStat1 = cudaMallocManaged(&d_C, s_C * sizeof(double));
      assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

      // Copy the data to the device data
      memcpy(d_A, A, s_A * sizeof(double));
      memcpy(d_B, B, s_B * sizeof(double));

      // Set up stuff for using CUDA
      int lda = m;
      int ldb = k;
      int ldc = m;
      const double alf = 1;
      const double bet = 0;
      const double *alpha = &alf;
      const double *beta = &bet;

      cublas_status = cublasCreate(&cublasH);
      assert(cublas_status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);

      // Perform multiplication
        cublas_status = cublasDgemm(cublasH, // CUDA handle
        CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, // no operation on matrices
        m, n, k, // dimensions in the matrices
        alpha, // scalar for multiplication
        d_A, lda, // matrix d_A and its leading dim 
        d_B, ldb, // matrix d_B and its leading dim 
        beta, // scalar for multiplication
        d_C, ldc // matrix d_C and its leading dim 
        );

      cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
      assert(cublas_status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS);
      assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

        // Destroy the handle
        cublasDestroy(cublasH);

      C = (double*)malloc(s_C * sizeof(double));
      memcpy(C, d_C, s_C * sizeof(double));

      // Make sure to free resources
      if (d_A) cudaFree(d_A);
      if (d_B) cudaFree(d_B);
      if (d_C) cudaFree(d_C);

      return;
  }

CudaMatrixTransformations::CudaMatrixTransformations() {
    cublas_status = CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    cudaStat1 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaStat2 = cudaSuccess;
  }
```

Then I created a gtest program to test my function. Where I passed a `double *result = NULL;` as my `C` parameter in my `MatrixMultiplicationDouble` function.

Snippet of gtest program (.cc file)

```cpp
TEST_F(MatrixTransformsTest, MatrixMultiplication) {
  double loc_q[] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8};
  double *q = loc_q;
  double loc_w[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
  double *w = loc_w;
  double *result = NULL;
  double loc_result[M_ROWS * M_COLS] = {14, 50, 86, 122, 23, 86, 149, 212};
  matrix_result = loc_result;

  size_t m = 4;
  size_t k = 3;
  size_t n = 2;

  perception_core::matrix_transform::CudaMatrixTransformations transforms;
  transforms.MatrixMultiplicationDouble(w, q, result, m, k, n);
  auto rr = std::addressof(result);
  printf("\nC addr: %p\n", rr); 

  std::cout << "result:\n";
  print_matrix(result, m, n);
  EXPECT_TRUE(compare<double>(result, matrix_result, m * n));
}
```

The routine in cuBlas works fine as I can see the result when I print the matrix inside the `.cu` file. However, when I try to access `result` in my gtest file, I get a seg fault. Upon further inspection I noticed that the address of the `result` pointer is **different** inside the `.cu` and in the `.cpp`. As an example I get:

```sh
C addr: 0x7ffc5749db08 (inside .cu)

C addr: 0x7ffc5749dba0 (inside .cpp)
```

I thought that by using Unified Memory I could access that pointer either from host or device. I can't seem to find an answer as to why this address changes and fix the seg fault issue. Is there something I'm missing about using Unified Memory? Thank  you!

Comment: You may be well-served by [`std::unique_ptr` specializations for CUDA](https://codedocs.xyz/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/unique__ptr_8hpp.html) from my [CUDA Runtime API C++ wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers): They would save you the error checks, nullness checks and `cudaFree()`'s at the end. There's a `unique_ptr` for managed memory in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you need:

```
cudaStat1 = cudaMallocManaged(&C, s_C * sizeof(double));
```

when you modify the numerical value of the `C` pointer, *that modification will not show up in the calling environment*.  That is the nature of pass-by-value, and the numerical value of the `C` pointer is being passed by value when you call `CudaMatrixTransformations::MatrixMultiplicationDouble`

So that line will work inside your function (perhaps), but the results won't be passed back to the calling environment that way.

I would suggest reworking your code so that you handle `C` in a fashion similar to how you are handling `A` and `B`.  Create an extra pointer `d_C`, do your `cudaMallocManaged` on that, then before returning, `memcpy` the results from `d_C` back to `C`.  This assumes you are allocating properly for the `C` pointer before calling this function.

Also note that at the end you are freeing `A` and `B` - that's not what you want, I don't think.  You should free `d_A`, `d_B`, and `d_C` before returning.

There are other issues with your code as well.  For example you refer to returning a `result` pointer but I don't see any evidence of that.  I don't see any pointer named `result`, actually.  Furthermore, the function prototype (in the class definition) doesn't match your implementation.  The prototype suggests a return `double*` whereas your implementation returns `void`.

And since I'm listing observations, I don't think your use of `addressof` is giving you the information you presume it is.  If you're going to compare numerical pointer values, you need to compare the values themselves, not the address of the location where those values are stored.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I updated the code with the suggestions you mentioned. Even after doing the `memcpy` from `d_C` to `C`, I still get the seg fault. I also added the .cc file where I use the `result` variable I mentioned. The `print_matrix()` function just accesses the values inside the pointer and this is where I get the seg fault.

Comment: your update won't work either.  You don't seem to be grasping what is needed.  The `C` pointer should be allocated for in the **calling environment**, not in any way in your function.  You should not use any allocation functions on that pointer in the `CudaMatrixTransformations::MatrixMultiplicationDouble`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I apologize; pointers are what always seem to haunt me when I code in C++.